# SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac:s3_pkt.c:535:

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, ssl, networking

I am using Requests js to make http requests. My script makes a GET request every 1 minute to an url that is secured over SSL. For 3 hour, everything works totally ( It made over 150 requests successfully). Suddenly, my node js app crashed and printed this error:

```
SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac:s3_pkt.c:535

at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:880:14) code: 'EPROTO', errno: 'EPROTO', syscall: 'write' }
```

The error stack trace pointed me to an error in request js result.

What does the above error mean? How to catch it and prevent it to happen again in the future?